# Calculating the ratio of green to red signal intensity for a list of images in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

I need to calculate the ratio of green to red signal for each individual image in a time lapse containing 100 images. These ratios need to be plotted in the same sequence as the images (i.e over time). So far, I can get the values for each signal of an individual image, but I am having trouble obtaining the values for a list of images and plotting the data in a coherent way in python.

For an individual image I used the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.array(Image.open("my_image.tif"))

red = im[:,:,0]
green = im[:,:,1]
plt.hist(red.ravel())
plt.hist(green.ravel())
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to python, so please forgive my ineptitude.

Comment: Can you describe, or better sketch, how your ideal output might look?

Comment: Ideal output would be a list of ratios in chronological order (according to image sequence), which I can use to generate line graphs to calculate signal decay curves etc.

Comment: Are the 100 frames in the one TIF? Can you share the image please?

Comment: Hi Mark, the frames are originally in one tif, but I have split the scenes for ease of use. A file with a shorter image sequence can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ZOzvx0yaVield3UUUtckRJSnM     Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
from skimage import io

# Load all tiff files in current directory
ic = io.ImageCollection('*.tif')

# Compute the ratio of red mean vs green mean for each image
# in the image collection
ratios = [image[..., 0].mean() / image[..., 1].mean() for image in ic]

# Plot the results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(len(ic)), ratios)
plt.show()
```

[image: red_vs_green_ratios]

Comment: Thanks Stefan,this really helps a lot! Applied it to my larger data sets and it worked perfectly. Is it possible to read multiple collections (separate files each with a collection of timelapse images) at once?

Comment: If you have TIFF files that store multiple images, that is certainly possible.  Multi-page TIFFs are read into arrays of shape `(pages, M, N, 3)`, so you can iterate, instead of only over ic, over the pages of the image itself: `images = io.ImageCollection('*.tif'); ratios = [[page[..., 0].mean() / page[..., 1].mean() for page in image] for image in ic]`.

Comment: Although this seems to work, I am having some trouble with the output. Do I just set the new plot range to the amount of pages in the file? At the moment, the plot generated only 5 intervals when reading 5 files containing 200 pages each. I need the plot to show the ratios over the entire 200 page time lapse for each file.

Comment: Files available here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ZOzvx0yaViZFRiR3o4TDV6dGs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just want a method to get answers, or if you are set on Python solution. Anyway, there don't seem to be any Python solutions forthcoming, so I am demonstrating a very simple method of getting answers with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Basically, I am just in the Terminal, running `convert` from the **ImageMagick** suite.

I load up an image, and get **ImageMagick** to calculate the mean of the red pixels  (`mean.r`) divided by the mean of the green pixels (`mean.g`):

```
convert Stack0000.tif -format "%[fx:mean.r/mean.g]\n" info:
0.715659
```

Now, if I want to get that same statistic for all files, I do the same thing again, but load all images, and also prefix each result with the filename (`%f`), like this:

```
convert Stack*.tif -format "%f %[fx:mean.r/mean.g]\n" info:
```

**Output**

```
Stack0000.tif 0.715659
Stack0001.tif 0.704214
Stack0002.tif 0.710086
Stack0003.tif 0.711458
Stack0004.tif 0.715423
Stack0005.tif 0.715327
Stack0006.tif 0.720593
Stack0007.tif 0.719039
Stack0008.tif 0.725973
Stack0009.tif 0.730682
Stack0010.tif 0.731558
Stack0011.tif 0.769168
Stack0012.tif 0.808623
Stack0013.tif 0.863428
Stack0014.tif 0.952388
Stack0015.tif 1.02525
Stack0016.tif 1.09869
Stack0017.tif 0.857375
Stack0018.tif 1.24331
Stack0019.tif 1.18171
Stack0020.tif 1.10395
Stack0021.tif 1.07511
Stack0022.tif 1.05641
Stack0023.tif 1.04386
Stack0024.tif 1.03314
Stack0025.tif 1.02554
Stack0026.tif 1.02284
Stack0027.tif 1.02046
Stack0028.tif 1.01807
```

---

Note that if you have all your images in a big stack of 29 pages of multi-page TIFF, you would use the *"scene number"* (`%s`) rather than the filename (`%f`):

```
convert StackOf29.tif -format "%s %[fx:mean.r/mean.g]\n" info:

0 0.715659
1 0.704214
2 0.710085
3 0.711457
4 0.715425
5 0.71533
6 0.720594
7 0.719038
8 0.725976
9 0.730682
10 0.731559
11 0.76917
12 0.808621
13 0.863424
14 0.952388
15 1.02525
16 1.09869
17 0.857375
18 1.24331
19 1.18171
20 1.10395
21 1.07511
22 1.05641
23 1.04386
24 1.03314
25 1.02554
26 1.02283
27 1.02046
28 1.01808
```

---

If you wanted to plot that, you could use `gnuplot` like this:

```
convert StackOf29.tif -format "%s %[fx:mean.r/mean.g]\n" info: > ratios.dat
gnuplot < plot.cmd
```

[image]

where `plot.cmd` contains:

```
set terminal png size 900,300
set output "graph.png"
set title 'Intensity Plot'
set ylabel 'Green:Red Ratio'
set xlabel 'Frame number'
plot "ratios.dat"  lt 3
```

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you so much. I installed Magick and it worked from my command line. The reason I was opting for python is that I've been getting familiar with SciPy and was hoping to eventually run a script for all my timelapses and manage to plot the signal decay curves and for all of them. ImageMagick seems to work just fine for now until I figure out something more robust. : Unknown field with tag 50839 (0xc697) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/921.

Comment: I'm not at a computer but try `-quiet` option or search for `-define tiff:ignore-tags` or somesuch.